# How do I save a password on a site where onblur is used in username/password fields?

Tags: browser, passwords, onblur

Looks like the use of onblur on username/password fields disables browsers' ability to offer you saving the username and password upon login. Is there a way to workaround this in Chrome? Instead of typing my u/p each time when I go to this site, I'd like to save them.

I prefer NOT to use extensions.

I also ran into this javascript on the same subject for a different site but wasn't able to make it work (to use it as a bookmarklet).

```
 javascript:{document.getElementById('txtUserName').value="HereGoesUsername";document.getElementById('txtPassword').value="HereGoesPassword";document.getElementById('lnkSignIn').click();void(0)}
```